# Populate a jquery dialog launched from a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, gridview

I have a gridview that I wish users to be able to click the View link and it pop up a jquery dialog with more data displayed from the row which the button is in. I am using a link button which displays the pop up but I wish to run server side (asp .net) prior to this in order to populate the fields on the jquery dialog before it is displayed

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnViewDetails" runat="server" Text="View" CommandName="ViewDetails"
                                CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerID")%>' 
                                OnClientClick="showDialog('viewCustomer');"></asp:LinkButton>
```

I have tried populating the controls in the RowCommand but this fires after the jquery popup has been displayed, resulting in the next time I click on a row's 'View' button, it displays the data from the previous row that was selected.

Greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to not trigger the dialog at **OnClientClick**. Instead you can trigger a AJAX call which populates the data to be displayed from the server side. And trigger the dialog on successful AJAX completion.

something like this

```
OnClientClick="TriggerAjax(yourInput)"
```

in javascript

```
function TriggerAjax(input) {
          $.ajax({
                      url: "SeverPage.aspx?input=" + input
                      cache: false,
                      success: function(response) {
                            showDialog(response);
                      }
                    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You inject javascript from your code-behind to open dialog something like this:

```
string script = "$(function(){showDialog('viewCustomer');});";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.Page.GetType(), "showdialog", script, true);
//Or if not using ScriptManager
//Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "showdialog", script, true);
```

In your showDialog you open the jquery dialog.
Check these:

[Show jQueryDialog from code-behind](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/12/18/part-2-showing-asp-net-validation-summary-in-a-custom-dialog-server-side.aspx)

[Inject javascript from code-behind](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/JavaScript_with_ASP_NET_2_0_Pages_Part1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks gbs, I have added the code to my RowCommand method which checks the e.Command name to be "ViewDetails". This pops up the dialog but then closes it straight away I am assuming due to the post back occurring. Do I need to use an updatepanel to get around this problem? Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Washburn:  Yes I am sure using UpdatePanel will take care of it. I think it should work without it as well. Which one did you try? If ScriptManager, you will atleast need ScriptManager on the page.